# Two-storey house, dissimilar Access Points, SSID same or not?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

My house has two floors, and due to its construction, I cannot deploy a single access point to reliably cover the whole house.

So, I deployed two access points:

- On the **second floor**, a Cisco Linksys E4200 running TomatoWRT. This AP is capable of both 2.4 and 5 GHz bands *simultaneously*.
- On the **first/ground floor**, a Cisco DPC3828S (terminates a cable connection). This AP is only capable of *either* 2.4 GHz *or* 5 GHz band, not at the same time. I set it to 2.4 GHz because the majority of users in my home are incapable of using the 5 Ghz band.
- Connection from the E4200 to the DPC3828S uses a Cat 5e cable, plugged into the "LAN" ports of each AP (hence, the E4200 acts only as a bridge to the DPC3828S), giving 1Gb connection between the APs.
- DHCP server only exists in the DPC3828S, because sometimes we shut down everything on the second floor, including the E4200.

My question is:

Due to the dissimilar bands, is it better to give each AP a different SSID (e.g., "pepoF1" and "pepoF2"), or would it be better to give both AP the same SSID (e.g., "HouseOfPepo")? And what's the reasoning?

Answer (score 4):

The only reason to use different names is if the devices aren't smart enough to switch between the bands.

If your devices are smart enough to switch between 2.4 and 5 ghz, make them all the same name with the same password. It will save human effort to configure both networks on the devices that support them.

Put another way, make it all one network until you run into issues.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the same SSID (but different channels). In this way you will have seem less coverage throughout the premises - with devices deciding in the better connection and switching automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you.  I would configure SSID "HouseOfPepo" on the Cisco Linksys E4200 (2.4GHz only) and I would set the DPC3828S to 2.4GHz and also configure it with "HouseOfPepo".  Now your entire house will have 2.4GHz coverage with SSID "HouseOfPepo".  Then, I would configure the Cisco Linksys E4200 5GHz to "PePoF1".  Now you have speedy 5GHz on the second floor just for yourself.  Your devices should be configured for both SSID's in their profiles... Everyone else should only have "HouseOfPePo" configured.  I know... I know... It's evil... But a necessary evil, nonetheless...